# Create a demo react-native app with official docs

Tags: react-native

I created a demo react-native app as official docs (https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup).

In the end i get this error:

[result after create a demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEn9a.png)

What should i do for next? :(

I's using react-native cli, macos, iOs simulator

Comment: Did you follow every step correctly?

Comment: I did it about 5 times, bro @Joshua

Comment: You'll need to connect your phone, probably try the `adb reverse` command

Comment: connect your phone, then run `adb devices` to see if adb discovers your devices. You should see your device, if so, then run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`